# How to find the contour graph and highlighted with 90 percentiles?

Tags: r, raster, contour, percentile

I have a raster image whose value ranges from 1 to 10.
I want to find the 90 percentile of mine raster data. And need to find the contour graph by highlighting the area having the 90 percentile. I want a figure for my raster data is attached below.  I am doing my analysis in R.

```
   library(raster)
   library(cartography)
   library(sf)
   library(SpatialPosition)

   r <- raster("E:/data.tif", package="raster")
   plot(r)
   contour(r, add=TRUE)
```

I got this type of image, but I wants the one with a shaded one (right side). Help on  making this picture will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data? I am not able to reproduce your image.

Comment: Reproducible data means? Actually I am very new in R so I don't get this term. You means raster file?- Quinten

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you looking for `image(r)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, don't have your data, but we can make an example raster like this:

```r
r <- raster(t(volcano[,ncol(volcano):1]))
```

From now on, the following code should work with your own raster too. We can get the 90th centile of our data like this:

```
centile90 <- quantile(r[], 0.9)
```

Now let's convert the raster to an x, y, z data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
colnames(df) <- c("value", "x", "y")
```

We can use the feature-rich `ggplot2` library for drawing the data. We will plot as a filled contour map and add a bright green contour at our 90th centile:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
  geom_contour_filled(bins = 10) +
  geom_contour(breaks = centile90, colour = "green",
               size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = hcl.colors(10, "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: It really work here but can you tell me in ggplot how can I add legend with the values of break? Because when I rune the code you provide here shows result without legend.

Comment: @user_3264 just remove `legend.position = "none",`

Comment: Can you tell me one last thing? How Can I apply the breaks on my data. for example in other example max is 500 and min is 1. so how can I put these values in this code and what the breaks after every 50 means "breaks = seq (0, 500, 50), limits = c(0,  500))+"